# program that takes value from the user and compares it to the another value, it keeps repeating untill the value is zero

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

**[CODE IS INCOMPLETE]**

i have created this program that asks user how much the item they need. for eg, asking user how much apples they need, user inputs something and then once all of they inputs are collected. the user starts to pick the the items (apples in this case), if the user picks up more than what he input, show and error saying they picked more items, same with the the zero, if they pick zero apples, show error but if the user picks up the item in range, for eg, he input value 10 but he picks up 4 apples, so now i have to store it and ask him to get a few more untill he gets what he input previously. i did all of the error stuff but i just dont know how to do the range one, i mean untill he gets it to zero

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int noApples = 0;
    int noOranges = 0;
    int noPears = 0;
    int noTomatoes = 0;
    int noCabbages = 0;
    char shop = ' ';

    int applespicked;
    int orangespicked;
    int pearspicked;
    int tomatoespicked;
    int cabbagespicked;
    

    printf("Grocery Shopping\n"
        "================\n");

   


    do
    {
      
        printf("How many APPLES do you need? : ");
        scanf(" %d", &noApples);

        if (noApples < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Value must be 0 or more.\n");
            printf("How many APPLES do you need? : ");
            scanf(" %d", &noApples);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("How many Oranges do you need? : ");
        scanf(" %d", &noOranges);

        if (noOranges < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Value must be 0 or more.\n");
            printf("How many ORANGES do you need? : ");
            scanf(" %d", &noOranges);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("How many PEARS do you need? : ");
        scanf(" %d", &noPears);

        if (noPears < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Value must be 0 or more.\n");
            printf("How many PEARS do you need? : ");
            scanf(" %d", &noPears);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("How many TOMATOES do you need? : ");
        scanf(" %d", &noTomatoes);

        if (noTomatoes < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Value must be 0 or more.\n");
            printf("How many TOMATOES do you need? : ");
            scanf(" %d", &noTomatoes);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("How many CABBAGES do you need? : ");
        scanf(" %d", &noCabbages);

        if (noCabbages < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Value must be 0 or more.\n");
            printf("How many CABBAGES do you need? : ");
            scanf(" %d", &noCabbages);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }


        printf("\n");
        
        
        
        printf("--------------------------\n"
            "Time to pick the products!\n"
            "--------------------------\n");

        if (noApples < applespicked)
        {
            printf("You picked too many... only %d more APPLE(S) are needed.\n", (applespicked - noApples));
        }

        else if (applespicked <= 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: You must pick at least 1!\n" );
        }


        


    } while (shop == 1);





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: None of your picked variables are initialized and the value assigned to `shop`  will cause the loop to end after one iteration because it is never changed. You might consider stripping this down to a single case and get that working then add the rest.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry, but my code hasnt been completed yet. cuz im stuck at this problem

Comment: You need to put each input in its own `while` loop. What if the user enters a negative number of apples (for example) twice? Also recommend putting that along with the error messages in a function, see how similar that code is for each item?

Comment: [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/xejq73vxb). All the warnings will disappear in the context of your larger program.

Comment: @yano what you shown me in the code has already been done, what im trying to do is when the user picks up an item and inputs value if its less than the desired value and greater than zero, i want to promt the user that you have to pick up a few more and have keep on asking until the desired value (the value he input before) is attained. for ex, he input that he wants 10 apples, and he picked five, program says that you have pick 5 more, when picks the remaing 5 five, program says "perfect"

Comment: A "minimal complete verifiable example" is needed.